# Expressjs session : undefined sessionid

Tags: mysql, node.js, session, express

I am getting null  sessionId in my expressjs application

here is **app.js** file

```
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/loginaction',loginaction);


//session handling
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
    secret: 'hellokitty',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
  }));
```

In my **loginaction.js** file which is located in `routes` folder.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

console.log("Session id"+req.sessionID);

//test session 
req.session.test= 'something';

});
```

But i will get session id as `undefined`

also `req.session.test` through another error cannot resolved `test`

Answer (score 0):

Your getting an unidentified on req.sessionid because you are never sending the sessionid to the client. You are requesting information the request doesn't have. Should try sending the sessionid in the initial login response. It should then remain persistent in the request after that (not sure on it's persistence tho, I use a different framework that keeps it persistent)